# Prolog - searching optimal response - tic tac toe

Tags: prolog

I am trying to understand how the response works for a game of tic tac toe. At this point I have `winningLine` facts that will tell if someone has won the game. The user can enter a position and the position will be filled, then Prolog will answer with a simple fact.
I'm trying to understand how to search for the most optimal response to a players input and send back a response.
I as thinking of using a `forall` and cycle through each user input to find the best spot for the response.

Here is what I have so far regarding the players:

```
% Specify the the 2 players and empty space for the board  
player(X) :- x(X).

% This will be the computer  
player(X) :- o(X).

% This is the blank space that we print out first and if the spot has not 
been taken yet  
blankSpace(X) :- not(player(X)).  

% Print the board 3 rows across by 3 columns wide
buildBoard :- printBox(1),printBox(2),printBox(3),nl,  
              printBox(4),printBox(5),printBox(6),nl,  
              printBox(7),printBox(8),printBox(9),nl.  

next_move(('[x]','[2]','[3]','[4]','[5]','[6]','[7]','[8]','[9]',8).
next_move(6). 


playersMove :- 
    repeat, write('Your turn, please choose a space between 1-9'),

    % Read Input
    read(X), 

    % Check if the number the user (X) entered is between 1 and 9
    between(1,9,X), 

    % Select the numbered blank space the user has specified
    blankSpace(X), 

    % Replace the numbered space with the text for the X player
    assert(x(X)).

computerMove :- 
    next_move(X), 
    blankSpace(X), 
    assert(o(X)).
```

My question: How do I find the user input and use the `computerMove` to find the optimal response on the board.

Comment: Looks better now guy, thanks

Comment: Of interest:  Wikipedia Tic-Tac-Toe [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe#Strategy) Notice the images to the right

Comment: Thank guy, I am fimilar with the strategy in tic tac toe however implementing that strategy in prolog is where I am failing to understand

Comment: I'm really confused by what is supposed to happen with `x/1` and `o/1`. Also, `assert/1` and `not/1` should be avoided, you should lean on `asserta/1` or `assertz/1` that make the semantics a little more explicit and `\+` instead of `not/1`. All that said, I have no idea what your `next_move` code is trying to do and I don't even see a representation of the board here. Where's the board?

Comment: Also, I would recommend you decide if you want to go with under_scores or camelCase, but mixing them like this is a little distracting.